# Using letters in function argument

Tags: r

Im trying to create a function that returns characteristic symbol to a defined value like this

"a" to 1
"b" to 2
"c" to 3

And where there is only one input argument (one of "a", "b" or "c") in the function. Like this: function(x), for example function("a") returns 1.

Answer (score 3):

We can convert  with matching to the default `Constant` `vector` `letters`

```
f1 <- function(arg1){
      match(arg1, letters)
  }

f1('a')
#[1] 1
f1('b')
#[1] 2
f1(c('a', 'b', 'c'))
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
letterToNumber <- function(x){
    which(x == letters)}

sapply(letters[1:10], letterToNumber)

 a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary like structure by using a named vector.

```
f <- function(x)
{
    dict <- setNames(seq_along(letters),letters)
    unname(dict[x])
}

f("a")
[1] 1
f("g")
[1] 7
f(c("a","z"))
[1]  1 26
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be faster than other solutions but won't fail if you don't feed a lower case letter :

```
foo <- function(x) utf8ToInt(x) - 96L
foo("m")
#> [1] 13
```